# CUDA programming in Rad Studio (Pascal)

Tags: delphi, cuda, gpu

I was wondering if there is any way to write programs to be run on GPU with RAD studio XE2 (or any other version of Pascal based IDEs) as we did with C++ and CUDA library in Microsoft Visual studio 2013?

Comment: To clarify, you want to write host code in Pascal and call CUDA APIs to run CUDA C code on the GPU?

Comment: I want to write the code in Pascal and then call the CUDA to run the code on the GPU.

Comment: Already discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918042/programming-cuda-using-delphi-or-freepascal