# Run C function with CUDA calls in Delphi program

Tags: c, cuda, freepascal

My objective is to have a Delphi( or freepascal) code, that will call the C function ***func*** like this one:

The C/Cuda file:

```
/* this is the "progcuda.cu" file */
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void foo(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n){
    /*
    add all the vector's element
    */
}


void func(int *a, int *b, int *c,int n){
    int *da,*db,*dc;
    cudaMalloc(&da, n*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&db, n*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&dc, n*sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(da,a,sizeof(int)*n,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(db,b,sizeof(int)*n,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dc,c,sizeof(int)*n,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    foo<<<1,256>>>(da,db,dc);
    cudaMemcpy(c,dc,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    /* do other stuff and call another Host and Device functions*/

    return;
}
```

The pascal main file:

```
// this is the "progpas.pas" file
program progpas;
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
uses unitpas;

var
    ...


begin
    ...
    func(a, b, c, len);
    ...
end.
```

The pascal unit file:

```
// this is the "unitpas.pas" file
unit unitpas;
{$link progcuda.o}
interface

uses ctypes;
procedure func(a, b, c : cpint32 , n:cint32); cdecl; external;
procedure foo(a, b, c : cpint32 , n:cint32);cdecl; external;

implementation

end.
```

I've found this post [Programming CUDA using Delphi or FreePascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918042/programming-cuda-using-delphi-or-freepascal)
, but it shows more a way to program CUDA in delphi.

I don't want to program CUDA in Delphi, I want to program in CUDA in pure C/C++ code and only call that C function in delphi.

What is the problem?
How can I link the .cu code to the delphi one?

I'm using linux ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I also have CUDA and VS in windows if necessary.

Note: if you guys could explain in detail how to do it, would help ( new to pascal and linking files )

---

I've already tried to generate the .o object file and link it in free pascal with
`$ nvcc progcuda.cu -c -o progcuda.o` then `$fpc progpas.pas`
but it fails at linking.

Note: I've tried once to link a normal .o generated by C code to pascal code, using gcc and freepascal compiler, and it worked, but if I use nvcc instead of gcc and rename the extension to .cu ( still same code), the linking fails.

---

note: new account in stack overflow, i cannot repply answers yet.

Comment: We would be able to help you better if you also included the exact linking error you got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about Delphi and FreePascal, but I do know about CUDA, C and C++, so maybe my solution will also work for you.

I'll be demonstrating it with a simple problem:

Content of `f.cu`:

```
int f() { return 42; }
```

Content of `main.c`:

```
extern int f();

int main() {
    return f();
}
```

The following works:

```
$ gcc -c -xc f.cu # need -xc to tell gcc it's a C file
$ gcc main.c f.o
(no errors emitted)
```

Now when we try replacing `gcc` with `nvcc`:

```
$ nvcc -c f.cu
$ gcc main.c f.o
/tmp/ccI3tBM1.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `f'
f.o: In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_0000704e_00000000-5_f.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
f.o: In function `__nv_init_managed_rt_with_module(void**)':
tmpxft_0000704e_00000000-5_f.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `__cudaInitModule'
f.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_0000704e_00000000-5_f.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The problem here is that `nvcc` adds references to some symbols from the CUDA runtime API when compiling `f.cu`, and these symbols have to be linked to the final executable. My CUDA installation is in `/opt/cuda`, so I will use that, but you have to replace it with wherever CUDA is installed on your system. So if we link `libcudart.so` when compiling the library we get:

```
$ nvcc -c f.cu
$ gcc main.c f.o -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
/tmp/ccUeDZcb.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This looks better, no strange errors, but it's still not finding the function `f`. That's because `nvcc` is treating `f.cu` as a C++ file, so it does name mangling when creating the object file, and we have to specify that we want `f` to have C, and not C++ linkage (see more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage).
To do that we have to modify `f.cu` like this:

```
extern "C" int f() { return 42; }
```

Now when we do:

```
$ nvcc -c f.cu
$ gcc main.c f.o -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
(no errors emitted)
```

I hope you manage to modify this to work with your language.

EDIT: I tried a bit more complicated example:

```
// f.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel() {
    printf("Running kernel\n");
}

extern "C" void f() {
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    // make sure the kernel completes before exiting
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

// main.c
extern void f();

int main() {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it I got:

```
    f.o:(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To fix it you also need to add the standard C++ libraries to the linker flags:

```
$ nvcc -c f.cu
$ gcc main.c f.o -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lstdc++
$ ./a.out
Running kernel
```

Comment: Maybe my answer and https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu147.html#x186-1890007.1.1 will be enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the files as @Goran Flegar explained:
Add `extern "C" int func(...);` to the .cu file. And then tried to compile/link the .cu code, but with no device calls (yet with device code), and all worked well.

but when i add a device call (  `foo<<<Nb,Nt>>>(...)`  ) and compile with:

```
$nvcc progcuda.cu -c
$fpc progpas.pas -ofinal.exe -Fl/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

i get:

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.4 [2017/12/13] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2017 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling prog1.pas
Linking sum.exe
/usr/bin/ld: aviso: link.res contém seções de saída; você se esqueceu -T?
/usr/bin/ld: sum.o: undefined reference to symbol '_Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
prog1.pas(16,1) Error: Error while linking
prog1.pas(16,1) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```

So there's still some missing libs.

---

Solution:

Found that linking the stdc++ and gcc_s lib to pascal solved the compilation problem.

```
unit unitpas;
// file "unitpas.pas"
{$LINK progcuda.o}
{$LINKLIB c}
{$LINKLIB cudart}
{$linklib stdc++}
{$linklib gcc_s}

interface

uses ctypes;
function func(x,y: cint32): cint32; cdecl; external;

implementation

end.
```

Run

```
$nvcc progcuda.cu -c
$fpc progpas.pas -ofinal.exe -Fl/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

and everything works.